# Set Tab key on the keyboard to only skip two instead of three space in dreamweavercs4

Tags: tabs, keyboard, dreamweaver

I am very surprised for the fact that seem there is no way to adjust the way how tab key works. I wonder if I can change the tab key's space skipped from default around 3~4 to fixed of 2 spaces ONLY.

Is it even possible? What about outside of Dreamweaver?

Environment is Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

What you can do is Go to:

Edit->Preference->Code Format-> Set Tab size = 2

Then restart the Dreamweaver.

DONE!

*At least I tried to help, not like someone just vote down when he or she does not even know the answer. So pathetic.*